# Drag link from another page into div using ondragover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wanting to have a link dragger which sets a specific input box's value to the link's url when the link is dragged over a div on my page. I have the code below which works but only for links that have been dragged from within the page itself.

My guess is that the link drop 'reciever' isn't being activated like it is when a link is dragged from within the page but I don't know why exactly.

The HTML for the div which used `ondrop` and `ondragover`:

```
<div id = "add" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
```

The related js:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    $("#linkin").val(data);
}
```

Thanks

EDIT: I used the URL as an example. The end goal involves pulling the page title from the link among other things.

Comment: I think when you start dragging from another page you set the focus to that page and your current page doesn't receive any event until you click on it to activate it. I don't know if this is possible

Comment: I know facebook chat uses it so it is possible I'm just unsure as to how exactly they do it

Comment: Is there a reason you want them to drop it on a div? You can drag -> drop a link to a text input without any code

Comment: Sorry I should have said. I just used the URL as an example. The end goal is to pull the page title among other things from the dropped link.